# How to use GLDATE and GL_DATE with Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am executing simple SQL queries with Toad for Oracle version 13.1.1.5.
I have been reading the Oracle documentations and still struggle with understanding the differences between GLDATE and GL_DATE.

At the moment I know how to use GLDATE to change the date format implicitly by casting the GLDATE to text (without tampering with the computer datetime settings), example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE to_char(GLDATE,'YYYYMMDD') = '20190105'
```

But what is GL_DATE (with the "_" character) then used for and why is the above code not working with GL_DATE (it throws the error ORA-00904 GL_DATE: invalid identifier)?

Moreover, how do environment variables connect with the GLDATE/GL_DATE commands?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question so that we can see the definition of those two columns. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: It is the name of a column in the table.
If you name your column gldate when creating the table, then you can not use gl_date. check you table Definition what columns you table has

Comment: GLDATE is a column name which is apparently used in Oracle Financials. To the best of my knowledge it is not a part of the standard Oracle database. Similarly, GL_DATE is apparently used as a column name in Oracle AP, another Oracle product which is not included as part of the standard Oracle database. And neither has anything to do with Toad, which is a database Integrated Development Environment (IDE). If you need to get the current date, use SYSDATE.

Comment: @hotfix Thank you! This was exactly my problem, it was the name of the column and I was thinking it was part of the command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The table has over 40 columns, and I was unaware that GLDATE was one of them. I believed that GLDATE was an Oracle command instead of a column name. Sorry, I am still a novice with more complex SQL commands.

Comment: Neither `GL_DATE` nor `GLDATE` is a command in Oracle nor is it a column in one of the Oracle system tables.